# Can I use TargetFileName to place a file up a directory within a Visual Studio Template?

Tags: visual-studio, templates

I have a .cs file with a base class that I want to use from within many projects.  I've first placed this cs file above the project folder (along side the .sln).  Then, within the project, I've changed the

`<Compile Include="BaseClass.cs">`
to
`<Compile Include="..\BaseClass.cs">`

This works, and the file icon then has a little shortcut arrow.

---

The problem comes when I want to export the project as a project template.  The BaseClass does not get included in the template because it is outside the project folder.  I've tried adding the BaseClass.cs to the template zip and adding
`<ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="..\BaseClass.cs">BaseClass.cs</ProjectItem>`
to the MyTemplate.vstemplate, but I get the error:
`A target file name within the VSTemplate file is invalid, it contains a fully qualified path`
If I remove the `..\`, it includes the file directly.
If I leave the `<ProjectItem>` out of the .vstemplate file, and just put `<Compile Include="..\BaseClass.cs">` in the .csproj file in the template, it looks for the file in `Users/me/AppData/Local...`.

How can I get the template to reference a file outside the project directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue which has not been solved by Microsoft : https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/565068/project-template-relative-file-path-does-not-work

Comment: The forum post I wasn't able to find.  Thanks.  I know it hasn't been fixed for VS2012, but happen to know if this has been fixed for VS2013?

Comment: Yes it is the same with VS 2013 unfortunately. I'm working on a workaround for this issue. The key idea is to create a Wizard for a template project.

Comment: This link is also very interesting : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/fr-FR/df624bb3-2b9b-4559-8e54-be721cefbcad/c-project-template-with-linked-file?forum=vsx

Comment: FWIW It's not fixed in VS2017, I can reproduce the same in VS2017.

Answer (score -1):

You should be doing the mapping of the folders in the VSTemplate and not in the project. The VS would not do any manipulation but in the template.

An example would be something like this. The below would copy the file from the "InnerFolder" to the root.

```
<Folder Name="InnerFolder" TargetFolderName="." >
    <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="Web.config">Web.config</ProjectItem>
</Folder>
```